# Python: Why are unrelated variables being assigned?

Tags: python, variables, game-development

I am writing an NES-styled game with python via pygame. I store level data in a series of 2-D arrays. Each level consists of three unique arrays (in addition to other things): collisionData(what blocks are being used), tileset(what palate is being applied to said block), and flipmap(mirroring of said blocks).

I have also added a function to animate certain blocks by switching values in these arrays (i.e. change the block at collisionData[0][3] from 25 to 27, causing the tile to change and appear animated). The specs for these changes include which of the three lists to modify, how long to do so, etc.

And this is where the crux of the problem lies. Here is some code:

```
            if Datafile["TileAnimations"][self.animList[item][2]][self.animFrames[item]][0] == "Layout":
                self.collisionData[self.animList[item][1]][self.animList[item][0]] = Datafile["TileAnimations"][self.animList[item][2]][self.animFrames[item]][1]
            elif Datafile["TileAnimations"][self.animList[item][2]][self.animFrames[item]][0] == "FlipMap":
                self.flipmap[self.animList[item][1]][self.animList[item][0]] = Datafile["TileAnimations"][self.animList[item][2]][self.animFrames[item]][1]
            elif Datafile["TileAnimations"][self.animList[item][2]][self.animFrames[item]][0] == "Tileset":
                self.tileset[self.animList[item][1]][self.animList[item][0]] = Datafile["TileAnimations"][self.animList[item][2]][self.animFrames[item]][1]
```

Now, this is *supposed* to pick the appropriate list and re-assign it's value based on the specs. For some reason, it instead picks the appropriate list--and then just applies the changes to all three lists.

I assumed that somewhere, I had created some sort of logical link between the three list on accident (i.e. set them to point at the same sector of memory or something like that). I was unable to find anything like that, or any reason for this to be happening at all.

Can anyone here shed some light on what sort of problem I'm dealing with? Thanks in advance.

-Sad Robot

Comment: How are `collisionData`, `flipmap` and `tileset` initialised? [Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) I suspect that is your issue.

Comment: @MichaelJones the variables are created like this:
`self.collisionData = self.file.get("Layout")
        self.flipmap = self.file.get("FlipMap")
        self.tileset = self.file.get("Tileset")`
It pulls data from a .json file. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Is `self.file` a single dictionary representing the world space?

Comment: @MichaelJones Yeah, pretty much. A .json storing level data is opened using the json library, and the result is stored in `self.file`. It doesn't contain **all** the info (sprite coordinates and such are separate), but most of it.

It may also be noteworthy that I experienced no issues with the function until I tried to add content to the beginning of each list (with separate function calls for each and separately declared [but content-wise identical] blocks)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I feel a little bit stupid now.

I had neglected to mention in my original post that I had been experiencing the issues while attempting to add to the arrays in order to make the level taller on a button click (it's for a level editor). After just looking at stuff, I noticed this in the function that adds vertical content:

```
fs1 = fullscreen.copy()
fs2 = fullscreen.copy()
fs3 = fullscreen.copy()
```

This only created shallow copies, meaning all the list content was pointers (assuming I read the docs properly). Literally all I had to do was change the code to this:

```
fs1 = copy.deepcopy(fullscreen)
fs2 = copy.deepcopy(fullscreen)
fs3 = copy.deepcopy(fullscreen)
```

and import the copy library, and **now it works *fine*.**

Turns out my original hypothesis about a logical link was right after all. Thanks to @MichaelJones for the help!

-Sad Robot